# Export from MySQL 5.5.18 from and Import in MariaDB 10.4.11

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have an utf-8 Dump from PHPMyAdmin (MySQL 5.5.18) with all Data utf-8 encoded:
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `work_id`, `titel`) VALUES
(1, 670557, 'LĂśsungen'),
(2, 833212, 'VerstĂśĂe'),
(3, 833212, 'ZuspĂ¤tkommen'),
...

If I import that File to MariaDB, Letters (ö, ä,...) were not shown on Website.
Same Server with two Databases! I found out that
ö in MySQL 5.5.18 is "Ăś" and 
ö in MariaDb 10.4.11 is "Ã¶"
I get crazy. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: need to use database gui (Sequel Pro, DataGrip) to get data as unicode and dump it as insert statements and then You can import it in mariadb.

Comment: thank you so much for your offer to help, but I/we found the problem: Old Database was set to Charset "Latin 2"...